# Are there nice generalizations of SPQR trees to k-connected components for k>3?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-algorithms

I'm curious how one should best understand the connections between the k-connected components when $G$ has minimum cuts of size $k>3$, or perhaps approximate minimum cuts produced by [Karger's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm).  [SPQR trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triconnected_component) answer this question for 2-connected graphs.  And obviously 1-connected graphs are simply a tree of their 2-connected components.

Comment: just a note: Karger's algorithm is not usually thought of as an approximation, but as a Monte Carlo algorithm. It produces the exact min cut with high probability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For edge connectivity rather than vertex connectivity, there's always the [Gomory–Hu tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomory%E2%80%93Hu_tree).

Answer (score 4):

Nagamochi and Ibaraki gave an algorithm to find a sparse $k$-node-connected subgraph of a given graph $G$ that contains $O(k n)$ edges where $n$ is the number of nodes in $G$. Not directly relevant perhaps but could be a useful preprocessing step.
http://www.springerlink.com/content/u334lr0418n1719u/