# Decomposing k-connected graphs into (k+1)-connected components

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

A connected graph can be decomposed into its biconnected components. This **block cutpoint tree** is unique. Similarly, biconnected graphs can be decomposed into triconnected components. The corresponding **[SPQR tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPQR_tree)** describes all the 2-vertex cuts in the graph and is uniquely determined from its graph.

This process does not generalize to higher connectivity. For example, given a triconnected graph $G$, there can be multiple "trees" describing all the 3-vertex cuts of $G$.

> Are there special classes of graphs such that $k$-connected graphs (in these classes) can be decomposed **uniquely** into their $k+1$-connected components.

Note that my question is slightly different from [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8627/are-there-nice-generalizations-of-spqr-trees-to-k-connected-components-for-k3).

Answer (score 8):

The following recent paper seems to be related to your question:

Connectivity and tree structure in finite graphs
Johannes Carmesin, Reinhard Diestel, Fabian Hundertmark, Maya Stein

http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.1611